# Link angular library projects together

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

Our angular application is getting refactor to be split up into multiple small libraries. However we are having problems creating the links in between the libraries. Most articles explain in details how they can be created, their advantages, but so far we did not find an example how to link them together.

The only way we found, to link them together, is to add the path of the compiled shared library to the tsconfig.

Example for `tsconfig.lib.prod.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial",
    "paths": {
      "company/shared": [
        "dist/company/shared"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However this would be quite hard to maintain, because we have to keep those references up to date, build the project in the right order, etc.

Is there a better way to do it?

Articles to this topic:

- https://medium.com/tunaiku-tech/creating-secondary-entry-points-for-your-angular-library-1d5c0e95600a
- https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/improve-spa-performance-by-splitting-your-angular-libraries-in-multiple-chunks-8c68103692d0

Comment: but maybe this just does not work the way I want it to work... https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1841#issuecomment-767710184

Comment: I would think you either want a monorepo approach or to publish the shared code as an NPM package.

Comment: can you give a bit more details what you mean with "a monorepo approach"? would I still be able to publish individual packages from this monorepo?

Comment: https://ngserve.io/3-patterns-to-sharing-components-in-angular/

Comment: https://kgotgit.medium.com/monorepo-pattern-setting-up-angular-workspace-for-multiple-applications-in-one-single-repository-4e14bc0d0cc0